# How to get fqdn of ip addresses in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, fqdn

On a machine there might be several IP addresses available. How can I find out all the belonging full qualified domain names (fqdn)?

#### Update:

I tried the following:

```
IPHostEntry he = Dns.GetHostEntry(Environment.UserDomainName);
foreach (IPAddress ipAddress in he.AddressList)
{
    string x = ipAddress.ToString();
    string y = Dns.GetHostEntry(ipAddress.ToString()).HostName;
}
```

I have a machine with 2 IP addresses, the ping using their fqdn returns the correct IPs. However, the code above always return me the one fqdn of the first IP.

My setup looks as follows:

**IP1:**
123.123.123.123
Name1

**IP2:**
456.456.456.456
Name2

Both ping and nslookup returns correct value.

The problem is that both rows

```
Dns.GetHostEntry("123.123.123.123").HostName;
Dns.GetHostEntry("456.456.456.456").HostName;
```

returns "Name1" (instead of "Name1" and "Name2").

However, the codes

```
Dns.GetHostEntry("Name1").HostName;
Dns.GetHostEntry("Name2").HostName;
```

work correctly.

Comment: Funny, the computer-name alone is of course the same in both lookups. Maybe you should try telling System.Net to lookup IP2 via a connection over IP2 ?

Answer (score 2):

You resolve each IP address to the netbios name.

```
Dim hostEntry As System.Net.IPHostEntry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry("192.168.115.54")
Console.WriteLine(hostEntry.HostName)
```

For example if I resolve my IP i get:

```
PC-MYNAME.MYDOMAIN.local
```

Then you can also use ActiveDirectory to enumerate the CurrentForrest (available domains).

Comment: thanks for your reply. How can I programmatically get a list of all ip addresses?

Comment: I mean all the ip addresses of my machine :-)

Comment: IPAddress[] allLocalAddresses = Dns.GetHostAddresses(string.Empty);

Comment: This does not give FQDN.